# How do I find the main class? Entry Point?

Tags: java, compilation

I'm getting Java code generated for me from an application.
I took the JRE and extracted all the files into a new directory.
There is a META-INF folder that has a MANIFEST.MF without any main method.

Witin this JRE is the class of the code I'm interested in however when I CMD the following...

> java Steve.class

I get this error...

```
Could not load for find Main Class Steve.class.
```

I'm assuming that somewhere in all these class files there is a Main class but how do I search all these documents to find it?   Is there an application?

Thanks!

Comment: *"I get this error..."*  No you didn't, please copy/pate error messages rather that paraphrase them. "*I took the JRE and extracted all the files"*  There is no need for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: every class that exposes this method signature:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { }
```

could be a main class launchable from the JVM and eligible to be put in the manifest to enable shell execution.

Second: when you launch a class in a JRE you must specify the fully qualified name of the class; for example if Steve.class file is in a tree structure such as com/mycompany/app, starting from the root of your application where the MANIFEST directory is, you should launch it, from the root directory, typing:

```
java com.mycompany.app.Steve
```

So if Steve exposes a main method and if you can correctly point to it from the root, you can launch it.

Comment: The x.x.x.Steve is cool and I got that working.  The error I'm getting is exactly what you put up on your msg.   I have the following. ....       public static void main(String[] args) -- How would I put this into the Manifest file?   How do I know what source codes I can attach?

Comment: To set your application entry point, you can add in your manifest file a line with ""; see here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html.

Comment: To visually search for classes that have a compliant main() method you can use an IDE, such as Eclipse, and visually inspect your classes. Eclipse will show you all classes (compiled or not) as trees, with methods fields and so on, and will let you perform searches on them.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need the `.class` suffix when invoking a Java program. Do it like this:

```
java Steve
```

To work out which class has a `main` method, you can use [`javap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html) (Java Class File Disassembler) on each class file. For example:

```
$ javap Foo
Compiled from "Foo.java"
public class Foo extends java.lang.Object{
    public Foo();
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```